# Flask socketio multiple connections

Tags: python, socket.io

I am trying to create a FB-chat like application. I have already started with the bare minimum of flask socketio implementation. So far, I already understand that client and server side communicate through a common handler. My current implementation is a free for all chat. for brevity i just show the handlers:

**Client side:**

```
 socket.on('message', function(msg) {
  $("#messages").append('<li>'+msg+'</li>');
  console.log('Received message');
 });
```

**Server side:**

```
@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
 print('Message: ' + msg)
 send(msg, broadcast=True)
```

Question:

How do I pass in arguments so I could have different chat ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is some chat rooms. Good news! Flask-SocketIO is now natively dealing with rooms.
You can import the modules like this :

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room,
close_room, rooms, disconnect
```

For joining a room, it looks like this :

```
@socketio.on('join', namespace='/test')
def join(message):
    join_room(message['room'])
    session['receive_count'] = session.get('receive_count', 0) + 1
    emit('my_response',
         {'data': 'In rooms: ' + ', '.join(rooms()),
'count': session['receive_count']})
```

You can find a complete example of code in the [Miguel's Github page](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/example/app.py) :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi sorry for previous answer.
You can get cookies from sid. If you save chat id into cookies. you can identify user id easily. 
this is my namespace code.

```
import socketio
import imp
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
gameDBModule = imp.load_compiled("ChatDatabase", "./game_chat/chat_database.pyc")
apiModule = imp.load_compiled("TotoAPI", "./game_api/__init__.pyc")

class GameChat(socketio.Namespace):

    def init(self):
        self.lastDataIndex = 0
        self.api = apiModule.TotoAPI()

    def on_join(self, sid, message):
        self.db = gameDBModule.ChatDatabase()
        sessid = self.getUserId(sid)
        try:
            info = json.loads(self.api.userinfo(sessid))
            userID = str(info[4])
        except Exception as e:
            userID = None

        self.emit('join', {'history': self.db.get_chathistory(), 'channel': message, 'moderator': False, 'user_id': userID}, room=sid)


    def on_connect(self, sid, environ):
        self.emit('connect', {'data': 'Connected', 'count': 0}, room=sid)
        print('GameChat Connected')

    def on_say(self, sid, message, environ):
        sessid =self.getUserId(sid)
        try:
            info = json.loads(self.api.userinfo(sessid))
            userID = str(info[4])
        except Exception as e:
            userID = None

        if userID !=None:
            userID = None
            #Save into History
            now = self.get_current_time(9)
            self.lastDataIndex = self.lastDataIndex + 1
            item = {
                'dataIndex': self.lastDataIndex,
                'bot': False,
                'date': now,
                'message': message,
                'role': 'user',
                'type': 'say',
                'user_id': userID
            }
            self.emit('msg', item)
            item['date'] = self.get_current_time(0)
            self.db.insert_chatting(item)



    def on_disconnect(self, sid):
        print('GameChat disconnected')

    def getUserId(self, sid):
        try:
            #Get UserID from Cookies
            cookies = str(self.server.environ[sid]['HTTP_COOKIE']).split(';')
            id = None
            for item in (cookies):
                name=str(item).split('=')[0].strip()
                value=str(item).split('=')[1].strip()
                if name.__eq__('ci_session'):
                    id = value
            return id
        except Exception as e:
            return None


    def get_current_time(self, diff):
        i = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours = diff)
        return i.isoformat()[:-3]+"Z"

this is the code using above name space

async_mode = 'eventlet'

import eventlet
import eventlet.wsgi
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request, make_response
import socketio
import imp

gameChatModule = imp.load_compiled("GameChat", "./game_chat/__init__.pyc")
apiModule = imp.load_compiled("TotoAPI", "./game_api/__init__.pyc")

sio = socketio.Server(logger=False, async_mode=async_mode)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app.wsgi_app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
api = apiModule.TotoAPI()
ns = gameChatModule.GameChat("/")
ns.init()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.register_namespace(ns)
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8880)), app)
```

I have implemented it in python 2.7 You seem use python 3. but you can implement my code.